# Invalid object name 'ACCOUNT_orders'? Spring-MVC Hibernate with annotation question

Tags: hibernate, spring, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I am new to Hibernate. I have Order and Account table in DB,

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ORDERS](
    [PRICE] [decimal](12, 2) NULL,
    [ORDERID] [int] IDENTITY(0,1) NOT NULL,
    [ACCOUNT_ACCOUNTID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ORDER] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ORDERID] ASC
)WITH (  STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF )  
)
```

Account Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ACCOUNT](
    [BALANCE] [decimal](12, 2) NULL,
    [ACCOUNTID] [int] IDENTITY(0,1) NOT NULL,
    [PROFILE_USERID] [varchar](250) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ACCOUNT] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ACCOUNTID] ASC
)WITH (  STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF )  
)
```

I am trying to do one to many mapping an One account has many orders. I have following classes:

```
@Table(name="ACCOUNT")
public class Account implements Serializable, IEntity{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int accountID;
    private double balance;
    private List<Order> orders; 

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int getAccountID() {
        return accountID;
    }
public void setAccountID(int accountID) {
    this.accountID = accountID;
}

public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
}
public void setBalance(double balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "ACCOUNT_ACCOUNTID",nullable=false,insertable=true,updatable=true)
public List<Order> getOrders()
{
    return orders;
}  
public void setOrders(List<Order> orders)
    {
        this.orders = orders;
    }       
}
```

Order Class:

```
@Table(name="ORDERS")
public class Order implements Serializable, IEntity
{
    private int orderID;
    private double price;
    @Column(name="ACCOUNT_ACCOUNTID")
    private Account account; 

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int getOrderID() {
    return orderID;
}
public void setOrderID(int orderID) {
    this.orderID = orderID;
}
public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL ,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
public Account getAccount() {
        return account;
    }
    public void setAccount(Account account) {
        this.account = account;
    }  
}
```

But when I try to access List method of HibernateTemplate with following HQL:

```
SQL_QUERY =" from Account as a where a.balance='"+bal+"'";
```

It gives me following ecxeption:

```
(JDBCExceptionReporter.java:72) - Invalid object name 'ACCOUNT_orders'.

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.microsoft.trade.service.TradeServiceImplementor.loginVerify(TradeServiceImplementor.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Help me please. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bidirectional OneToMany association here : an account has many orders, and an order has one account. One of the association is the inverse of the other one. You must thus define the mapping for this association on one side (usually, the many side: this is mandated by JPA), and declare that the association is the inverse of another one on the other side (the one side) :

```
@Entity
public class Account implements Serializable, IEntity{
    // ...
    private List<Order> orders; 

    // mappedBy is used to indicate that this association is the inverse of the association
    // mapped by the account property of the Order entity
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="account")
    public List<Order> getOrders() {
        return orders;
    }       
}

@Entity
public class Order implements Serializable, IEntity {
    // ...
    // a relationship to another entity is never mapped by @Column. You can't have annotations 
    // on the field and the getter. Choose one or the other, and be consistent for all 
    // the properties of the entity
    private Account account; 

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ACCOUNT_ACCOUNTID")
    public Account getAccount() {
        return account;
    }  
}
```

Note that most of the time, it's wrong to have a cascade all on the many side of a relationship. You don't want an account to be deleted when an order is, do you? The account holds the orders, not the reverse.

Finally, regarding your query: it's not a SQL query, it's a HQL query. And you should not use concatenation, but bind parameters : this is safer (no injection attack), clearer (no quoting necessary, more readable), and faster :

```
String hql = "from Account a where a.balance = :theBalance";
Query query = session.createQuery();
query.setParameter("theBalance", new BigDecimal("12.5");
```

Comment: @JB Its not working, it says: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Collection of elements must not have mappedBy or association reference an unmapped entity: com.trade.model.Account.orders

Comment: Have you annotated the Order class with javax.persistence.Entity?

Comment: Yes both classes(Account and Order) are annotated with @Entity.

Comment: And are you sure the import statement for Entity is javax.persistence.Entity, and not org.hibernate.annotations.Entity?

Comment: Are the entities declared in the hibernate.cfg.xml file? If not the case, then edit your question and add the new code.

Comment: Here it is, in My `sessionFactory` bean I forgot to add order class.
Thank you very much for responce.